# How to go back in the window with cucumber and watir web-driver?

Tags: cucumber, watir-webdriver

I need to go back in the browser. How can I make it with cucumber? I use watir web-driver.

And how can I close pop up in window?

Comment: Please create a new question for pop up problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will go back in a browser:

```
browser.back
```

I could be more specific if you had provided relevant code.